# How to insert on runtime on odt document using jodreports and java

Tags: java, image, insert

I need to insert various images in a doc or odt document using java, the images are generated on runtime. At the time I am tempted to use jodreports because it is very easy to generate the template of the final document, but I am stuck because I cannot find any kind of documentation telling me how to insert images. If you can answer my question please post a code snippet or tell me which other library I can use.

Thanks a lot for your help(and sorry for my bad English).

Answer (score 1):

Create a `ImageSource`-object in your class.

```
ImageSource imagen =
new RenderedImageSource(ImageIO.read(new File(ruta_fisica_imagen)));
```

Add this object into Map object

In template define `jooscript.image(name)`

More information, the document is Spanish
http://www.montesinos.org.es/2010/11/jodreports-mini-how-to.html

Answer (score 1):

In my page https://xbrowser.altervista.org/informatica-portata/odt-converter/
you can find step by step how to implement your question.

Libraries are:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import net.sf.jooreports.templates.DocumentTemplate;
import net.sf.jooreports.templates.DocumentTemplateException;
import net.sf.jooreports.templates.DocumentTemplateFactory;
import net.sf.jooreports.templates.image.FileImageSource;
```

This is the method

```
private Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();;
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

private void createOdt() {

DocumentTemplateFactory documentTemplateFactory = new DocumentTemplateFactory();
DocumentTemplate template = null;

File inputFile = new File("/path/template.odt"); //inserire il path relativo alla posizione del template .odt
try {
template = documentTemplateFactory.getTemplate(inputFile);
log.debug("input file ok -> " + inputFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
log.error(e);
}
try {
tmpFile = File.createTempFile("odt_", ".odt");

data.put("qrcode", new FileImageSource(new File("/img/src/qrcode.jpg"))); //qui è possibile generare per esempio un qrcode
template.createDocument(data, new FileOutputStream(tmpFile));

log.debug("output file temporaneo creato ("+ tmpFile.getAbsolutePath() + ")..");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
log.error(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
log.error(e);
} catch (DocumentTemplateException e) {
log.error(e);
}
}
```

At this point it is necessary that in the .odt template an image is inserted with the following modality:

1. Insert an image
2. Double click on the image to go into properties of image
3. Select "options" tab
4. In the field "Name" insert: jooscript.image(qrcode)

As you can see the name of the image shows qrcode which is exactly the name of the hashmap key in our code(`data.put("qrcode")`).

In this way it is possible to show dynamically generated images from the java code in a template defined in .odt.

I hope you have been helpful

Comment: English please.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to confirm that approach from @Jarabid works.

```
//visual signature
ImageSource signatureImage = 
      new RenderedImageSource(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/Signature.png")));
data.put("signature", signatureImage);
```

I'm using LibreOffice on the Mac and what I did was:

- Insert Image From File (used placeholder image)
- Double click on image to bring up Picture properties
- Select the "Options" tab
- In name paste: jooscript.image(signature)

Worked perfectly first try. Happy :)